# copying a string pointer from object x to another with (*this).ptr instead of x.ptr

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I am learning about C++ special members in detail.

I was fiddling with some code and trying different ways, then came across this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Example5 {
public:
    string* ptr;
public:
    Example5 (const string& str) : ptr(new string(str)) {}
    ~Example5 () {delete ptr;}
    // copy constructor:
    Example5 (const Example5& x) : ptr(x.ptr) {}
};

int main () {
    Example5 foo ("Example");
    Example5 bar (foo);

    cout << foo.ptr << endl << bar.ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

This code shows a shallow copy of the object with the expected result:

```
0x505348
0x505348
```

While this code does not appear to perform a shallow copy:

```cpp
// copy constructor: deep copy
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Example5 {
public:
    string* ptr;
public:
    Example5 (const string& str) : ptr(new string(str)) {}
    ~Example5 () {delete ptr;}
    // copy constructor:
    Example5 (const Example5& x) : ptr((*this).ptr) {}
};

int main () {
    Example5 foo ("Example");
    Example5 bar (foo);

    cout << foo.ptr << endl << bar.ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

With this result:

```
0x505348
0x505278
```

Isn't `*this` just pointing to the object and its members?

I was expecting the same outcome.

Comment: You do know that `string* ptr;` does not make much sense do you? std::string is a helper class that should help you to avoid to use new/delete yourself.  [avoid calling new/delete  explicitly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly). Also try to avoid `using namespace std`. Just make the member a std::string instead of a pointer and let C++ create the (implicit) copy constructor for you

Comment: *i was fiddling with codes and trying different ways,* -- `int main() { Example5 foo("foo"); Example5 ("bar");  foo = bar; }` -- You do realize that this will fail due to a double delete error?

Comment: `ptr((*this).ptr)` initialises `ptr` with the current value of `ptr` which is uninitialised, not sure what you're trying to do here?

Comment: e.g. see gcc compiler warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/xqTqTvx7G

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes i do ... i was just trying (*this).ptr to see if it gives same result as x.ptr but it did not
which is a good thing i suppose but im trying to understand why it does.

Comment: @PepijnKramer about string* ptr yes i do know ... it was just an example in a tutorial at cplusplus
there is more to go in c++ learning for me i suppose :)

Comment: Ok good to know you know :) And one thing... I've been using C++ since 1995 and I keep learning (also because C++ keeps evolving).

Comment: @AlanBirtles so isn't `ptr((*this).ptr)` similar to `bar.ptr = foo.ptr` ? or is it `bar.ptr = bar.ptr` i see where the mistake is :(

Comment: yep, its `bar.ptr = bar.ptr`

Comment: @AlanBirtles man `*this` is confusing ;)... much thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the 1st code simply shallow-copies the value of `ptr` from one object to another.  That will cause problems when the two objects go out of scope and get destroyed, as their destructors will both try to `delete` the same memory.

In the 2nd code, initializing `ptr` with `(*this).ptr` is effectively a **no-op** (actually, it is **undefined behavior**, since you can't read a value from an uninitialized variable).  Since you are initializing `ptr` with itself, its final value will be *indeterminate*.

The correct code to make the copy constructor deep-copy `ptr` would be:

```
Example5 (const Example5& x) : ptr(new string(*(x.ptr))) {}
```

Or, in C++11 and later, you can [*delegate*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Delegating_constructor) to the other `Example5` constructor that takes in a `string`:

```
Example5 (const Example5& x) : Example5 (*(x.ptr)) {}
```

---

Also, be sure to add a viable copy assignment `operator=` to `Example5` to finish implementing the [Rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).